# How to get the value from the url in the function argument?

Tags: 7

When I pass **nid** value in the url like '/abc/**[nid]**', I want a function to receive that nid value

the code is as the following:

```
function ort_view_menu() { 
          $items['ox_view'] = array( 
            'title' => 'Viewed Details', 
            'description' => 'g a report', 
            'page callback' => 'abc', 
            'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, 
            'access callback' => TRUE, 
           ); 
return $items;
}

function abc($nid) { 
$rows = array();
$node = node_load($nid); 
}
```

What changes do I need to make in hook_menu() to catch the nid value in the page callback function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is either:

- [`arg()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function:

  > Returns a component of the current Drupal path.
  >
  > When viewing a page at the path "admin/structure/types", for example,
  >   arg(0) returns "admin", arg(1) returns "structure", and arg(2) returns
  >   "types".
- or [Callback Arguments](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7#sub_callback_arguments):

  ```
  function mymodule_menu() {
      $items['abc/def'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
        'page arguments' => array(1, 'foo'),
      );
      return $items;
    }
  ```

  When path 'abc/def' is requested, the page callback function will get 'def' as the first argument and (always) 'foo' as the second argument.

Comment: one thing to remember is after every change in hook_menu() you should clear the cache for the function to work..:)